# Jest Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I am running this warning when I run Jest to test my react native app

> 'Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to
> `Image`.'  This relates to an ImageBackground tag not an Image tag.

However, the image renders fine when just running the emulator and there is no warnings in the console, just when I run Jest.

I *think* my syntax is correct. Any ideas why this is happening? All tests are passing, just this one warning.

```
<ImageBackground
  source={{ uri: root + thumbnail }}
  style={styles.backgroundThumbnail}
/>
```